# Getting characters in textarea on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the number of characters in a textarea. This needs to update at every keystroke. So i used this simple function:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'textarea', function () {
    var count = $(this).val().length;
    console.log(count); 
});
```

Now the problem is, If i try to type very fast, the count repeats. We can see the repetition in console. What is the reason behind this repetition ? Also how can i avoid it ?
Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w6mzzfd8/

Thanks !

Comment: I am not able to force a repeated length in console. Remember that the event is called only when you release the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As per Docs:**

> The keypress event is sent to an element when the browser registers keyboard input. This is similar to the keydown event, except in the case of key repeats. If the user presses and holds a key, a keydown event is triggered once, but separate keypress events are triggered for each inserted character. In addition, modifier keys (such as Shift) trigger keydown events but not keypress events.

**Solution:**

Use `keydown` instead of `keyup`

**Code:**

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'textarea', function () {
 var count = $(this).val().length;
 console.log(count); 
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0s7cwyj4/)**

Comment: Try "keypress" if you don't want shift/ctrl etc from showing repeated numbers.